# Private DLL Functions are Publicly Accessible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, permissions

I have generated a Win32 DLL using C++ in Visual Studio 2008.  All of my functions are defined within the only class native to the new DLL.  Some functions are declared as `private`, and others are `public`.  I'm using Dependency Walker to objectively verify the accessibility of the functions in my DLL.  My class is declared as `__declspec(dllexport) MyClass { /* ... */ };`.  Does this mean that all the class functions are going to be publicly accessible, regardless of their permissions?

*Is there perhaps a compile/project option that I need to set to enforce privacy permissions in the compiled DLL?*

Comment: I think part of the answer to that is whether the class has any virtual methods.

Comment: Please note that public/private in C++ are _not_ a security feature. It's just some syntactic sugar, not intended for enforcing privacy.

Comment: VS compiler controls private/protected/public accessibility by changing the way the compiler mangles the function names. So, even if someone changes the header, it will still be impossible to access private members without recompiling your library.

Comment: @Roman: There's certainly something to what you wrote, but I wouldn't diss encapsulation as "syntactic sugar". It's one of the cornerstones of OOP.

Comment: @Vitor, that's very interesting, I did not know that. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Vitor: Are you sure about this? Because then the often cited `#define private public` wouldn't work with VC. And I seriously doubt that.

Comment: @sbi @Mark Ransom http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Name_Mangling#Function_2

Comment: @sbi yes, I just wanted to emphasise that it's not enforced. And some OOP languages don't have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the compiler depends on the integrity of the .h file with the class definition to enforce the privacy of class members. If someone modifies the class definition, the loader will be more than happy to link those private functions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I wrote the class.  It currently exists only on my local machine, so no one has modified it.  Is there perhaps a compile/project option that I need to set to enforce privacy permissions in the compiled DLL?

Comment: @Jim, you're worrying too much. As long as your class definition does not change then the compiler won't let you use those private functions, no matter how exposed they are in the DLL.

Comment: I started playing with the new DLL, and it makes sense now.  Thank you.  I accepted your answer because you responded first.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Access specifiers are a pure compiler *front-end* feature. They won't show up in generated code.

In order to use your class in their code, users need the class definition, usually provided in form of one or more `.h` files. Access specifiers are in there, which prevents users of the class to access private parts - *unless they modify the header*.

Your class *has* to export all member functions, even the private ones, because they could be referenced from public inlined functions. The code of inlined functions is expanded into the caller's code. So, at the machine code level, ***users of your class might actually have to be able to call private functions***.

Comment: Do you mean that the DLL contains the privacy information, so if someone tries to access the function, they will be unable to do so?

Comment: @Jim: No. The DLL contains just the machine code. Whether something is public or private is enforced by the compiler compiling your class' users' code, according to what it finds in your class' definition in its header.

Comment: @sbi: I started playing with the new DLL, and it makes sense now.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, `friends` are another feature that would require private functions to be visible.

Comment: A smart compiler might of course notice that there's no way that a private function could be called and omit these exports. As Steve Townsend noticed, the specs are minimal: ` __declspec(dllexport)` only promises to export public members. Private members are not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

No - only public members of a class exported using `__declspec(dllexport)` will be visible from outside.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx

> To export all of the public data
>   members and member functions in a
>   class, the keyword must appear to the
>   left of the class name as follows:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) CExampleExport : public CObject
{ ... class definition ... };
```

Comment: For some reason, it's exporting all the member functions regardless of privacy or ordinal.

Comment: @Jim - how can you tell - have you actually compiled and run a call to a private member function?  Use `dumpbin /exports myname.dll` from a Visual Studio command prompt to see what's really callable from outside.

Comment: I started playing with the new DLL, and it makes sense now.  Thank you.

Comment: @SteveTownsend The private functions are exported as well (until VS2013 at least), this is also visible using dumpbin or Dependency Walker. Maybe this will change in the future, but so far the MSDN only says that this is how you export all public data members with one statement. It does not say anything about what happens to private members.